# adding solar cells to PVLIB and modeling them

Tags: pvlib, solar

I am new to Pvlib and just started few days ago. We have four different solar cells installed in our university. I have the specifications of the four cells including Isc, Voc, Vmpp, Impp etc. I want to add these cells into the PVlib library and then do further modeling on each of them. Can you please guide me how to proceed. I just need to know that how can I use the specifications of each solar cell mentioned below to integrate them with pvlib. In the cec and sandia database we only have silicon based solar cells. I would be grateful for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried anything you can share?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have Voc, Isc, Imp, & Vmp at STC conditions you may be able to use the [pv parameter estimation functions](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#estimating-pv-model-parameters) but you will have difficulty coming up with temperature coefficients, but perhaps you have those already separately? Then use `calcparams_<model>` where model is the same as what you estimated parameters for, one of CEC, PVsyst, Sandia, or DeSoto. This will give you the temperature and irradiance specific parameters to use in `singlediode` to get max power (or any operating point) for each timestep corresponding to the temperatures and irradiances of interest.

Comment: Thank for your help.                                                                                                                
I have datasheets for the four modules (monosi, polysi, amorphous, cigs) and they contain the Voc Isc etc and also contain the temperature coefficients for each.  I need to model IV curves for each of these modules. Can you tell me how to do that when cigs and amorphous is not present in the cec or the sam database.

Comment: Furthermore for using calcprams_<model> I need to find I_L_ref , I_o_ref , R_sh_ref, a_ref and R_s. How do I calculate them ?                                                                                                               I also need to know that what is CEC, PVsyst , Sandia and Desoto.

Comment: I see you've already started a thread in the [pvlib Google group](https://groups.google.com/g/pvlib-python/c/c7RN4cSnmxw) I think that's the best place to continue this discussion. Happy to help you, altho I think you're already in the most capable hands. See you over there!